# Scrapy Xpath not contains command not functioning

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm using not contain in my xpath but it doesn't seem to work as it still fetches the element under the h2 titled "What I dislike about the company" which is in my not contain.

HTML:

```
<div itemprop="reviewBody" class="review-body"><h2 class="h3">Suggestions for improvement</h2><p></p><ul><li>Better managers the ones they have suck</li></ul><h2 class="h3">What I like about the company</h2><p>Great company thanks again for sure</p><h2 class="h3">What I dislike about the company</h2><p>The fact they didn't care about my health</p></div>
```

Xpath:

```
response.xpath("(//div[@class='review-body'])/h2[contains(.,'What I like about the company') and not(contains(.,'What I dislike about the company'))]/following-sibling::p/text()").getall
```

I need the code to pull the 'p' under h2 titled "What I like about the company" but not the 'p' under "What I dislike about the company", Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "pull the 'p'"? What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that in a hurry but I want to fetch the <p>Great company thanks again for sure</p> but not <p>The fact they didn't care about my health</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the text of the first `p` after the `h2` containing specific text.

To achieve this, just go step-by-step:

- get the wanted `h2`: `//h2[text()="What I like about the company"]`
- get its first sibling which is a `p`: `/following-sibling::p[1]`
- get its text: `/text()`

Putting it all together, we get this:

```py
>>> sel.xpath('//h2[text()="What I like about the company"]/following-sibling::p[1]/text()').get()
'Great company thanks again for sure'
```